# Как описать неравномерное движение по кругу в виде функции?

Tags: алгоритм, анимация, математика

Я пытался описать движение по кругу (на самом деле эллипсу, но это не важно) с помощью функции. Равномерное движения по кругу успешно реализовал с помощью функций:

```
y = sin(t)` и `x = cos(t)
```

А вот с неравномерным движением не получается.
Я собрал функцию `c = f(t)`, значение которой на разных участках увеличивается и уменьшается.

Затем добавил `c` в функции равномерного движения по кругу:

```
y = sin(c*t)` и `x = cos(c*t)
```

oднако результат не соответствовал ожиданию, скорость движения увеличивалась и уменьшалась не плавно, а рывками.

Движение делало развороты, а его скорость не коррелировала со значением `c`.

Пример графика функции можно [посмотреть здесь](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jejyw9nzwi).

Есть ли какой либо способ, описать неравномерное движение по кругу в виде функции?

Comment: [так?](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iwwfv3pg8s)

Comment: Я бы попробовал нечто такое `c=K *sin(t) + t`. При этом обратите внимание, что при больших значениях t из-за дискретности типов `float/double` могут быть "скачки" между соседними значениями (из-за ограниченности точности мантиссы).